# Python Openpyxl pick cell to start printing numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, openpyxl

So I just started using openpyxl and I'm trying to print my numpy array to a specific cell.  I was able to just print the array to excel starting in the first cell (see code below) but don't know how to pick a cell to start printing.  In my example, I convert the list to a numpy array because my work software outputs a numpy array.

```
exlist = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'scrappaper3.xlsx'
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = 'scrap3'
for x in xrange(exlist.shape[1]):
    ws1.append(exlist[:,x].tolist())
wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

outputs starting in cell A1 but want to specify the first cell to output

```
    1   6   11
    2   7   12
    3   8   13
    4   9   14
    5   10  15
```

I tried using the example from openpyxl with code similar to below but I don't know how to configure it as I get an error saying it can't convert to excel.

```
ws1.cell(column=col, row=row).value = exlist
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment openpyxl does not support NumPy types so you will need to convert these standard Python types. This is easy for integers, floats or bools, NaN should be converted to None. NumPy datetimes should be converted to Pandas Timestamps.

openpyxl 2.4 will be adding support for NumPy and Timestamp types but not datetime64.

Comment: But it was able to print the numpy array to excel, just not able to choose a cell to print to.